# Record movements in adobe flash cs5

Tags: flash, flash-cs5

Can someone please help in recording movements while dragging an object and when the object is dropped the record event will stop and the recorded movement will be animated by Play button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set up an array that will store recorded information:

```
var recording:Array = [];
```

Set up a method that will add information to this Array:

```
function record(target:MovieClip):void
{
    recording.push(new Point(target.x, target.y));
}
```

Do this when you start dragging your object:

```
recording.length = 0;

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _record);
function _record(e:Event):void
{
    record(yourObject);
}
```

Do this when you stop dragging your object:

```
removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _record);
```

Do this when you click replay:

```
recording.reverse();

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _playRecording);
function _playRecording(e:Event):void
{
    var step:Point = recording.pop();

    yourObject.x = step.x;
    yourObject.y = step.y;

    if(recording.length < 1)
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, _playRecording);
}
```

---

### Storing your recorded data for later use:

You can use this method to convert your `recording` array into a string:

```
function collapse(data:Array):String
{
    var joined:Array = [];

    for each(var point:Point in data)
    {
        joined.push(Math.round(point.x) + ":" + Math.round(point.y));
    }

    return joined.join("$");
}
```

Which will end up something like:

```
trace(collapse(recording)); // 48:47$29:19$4:26$20:35$1:48$3:16$12:24$27:30$0:24$19:48
```

You'll then be able to use this to create your `recording` array:

```
function expand(data:String):Array
{
    var out:Array = [];
    var base:Array = data.split("$");

    for each(var fragment:String in base)
    {
        var coords:Array = fragment.split(":");
        var point:Point = new Point(coords[0], coords[1]);

        out.push(point);
    }

    return out;
}
```

Which works like so:

```
var previousData:String = "48:47$29:19$4:26$20:35$1:48$3:16$12:24$27:30$0:24$19:48";
var recording:Array = expand(previousData);

trace(recording); // (x=48, y=47),(x=29, y=19),(x=4, y=26),(x=20, y=35),(x=1, y=48),(x=3, y=16),(x=12, y=24),(x=27, y=30),(x=0, y=24),(x=19, y=48)
```

Comment: thank you sir Marty,  i'm currently developing my basketball playbook application for my final project..can you please help me also in capturing  my current screen state and be able to save and load it using a button..so that i can load and save plays

Comment: So you're after a way to store the save as a string that you can load later on?

Comment: Sir can i send my project?so that you can see my application?

Comment: sir i just encountered error for

 function _record(e:Event):void
{
    record(yourObject);
}


Scene 1, Layer 'Actions', Frame 1, Line 328 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

thanks for the help

Comment: You need to `import flash.events.Event;`.

Comment: sir i've already have the import statement. but still getting some error...:(

Comment: please help..i cant run my application anymore..having troubles for import.events.Event

Comment: sir marty can i send my .fla to you?please check my work..still having difficulties though, thanks for the help